# How to call ProgresSql stored procedure with timestamp parameters

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a very simple stored procedure which I'm trying to execute in c#

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_documents(  
    p_issue_date TIMESTAMP
)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin   
    
    select * from documents ;
    
end; $$;
```

Repository.cs

```
var test2 = await _dbContext.QueryAsync<Documents>("get_documents", new
{
    p_issue_date = input.Date //This is a DateTime object
}, isStoredProcedure: true);
```

I get the error message  `No procedure matches the given name and argument types` The parameter incoming is timestamp **with** time zone instead of timestamp **without** timezone. May I ask how do I execute sproc with timezone without parameters passed.

Comment: A procedure isn't meant to return anything to begin with. You need to define a set returning function that can be used using `select * from get_documents(...)`

Comment: Hey @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for your input. But that's irrelevant to the question asked. This was a small reproducible example to help illustrate the problem at hand.

Comment: I know, but once you succeed in passing a timestamp parameter, running the procedure will result in the error "*Query has no destination for result data*"